# Audio Recording Stop when play video file in other Apps

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios9, avaudiosession

We have functionality for background recording in app. It is working fine when app in background mode but it is stop when we open other app and play video file in other app then audio recording stop to recording sound in it.How can we continue recording even without stop recording when other app play video file.

Thanks

Comment: Try AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers

Comment: @JonSnow i used this code but not works :func audioSessionSettings() {
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord, with: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.mixWithOthers)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }